# How can I retrieve an item from a listviewer after I double click it, in a view

Tags: java, eclipse, view

I Have created a new view in Eclipse, by following a tutorial. I have created a listviewer with certain items. I have implemented a doubleClickListener, however I need to get the String of the item I doubleclicked in order to perform some action. So I have the following code:

```
viewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {

            try{
                if( /*ITEM CLICKED, MATCHES STRING "A"*/ ){
                    /*DO THIS */
                }else if( /*ITEM CLICKED, MATCHES STRING "B"*/ ){
                    /*DO THAT */
                }

            }catch (Exception ex){
                throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: checkout ur event ..it will have your selected item..upon which you can further apply your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `getSelection()` method of the `DoubleClickEvent` to get the selection:

```
@Override
public void doubleClick(final DoubleClickEvent event)
{
  IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)event.getSelection();

  if (selection == null || selection.isEmpty())
    return;

  Object sel = selection.getFirstElement();

  // TODO 'sel' is the object from your content provider
}
```